# Pandas ignore/drop strings between rows in a csv file but dropna dosen' seem to work

Tags: python, pandas, csv

With the Help of Jared and little bit research on my own I came up with the following solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv(DATAFILE_INPUT, sep='\t', skiprows=8, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False, decimal=',')
df.columns =['Zeit', 'Zyklus', 'Weg','Kraft', 'Dehnung', 'Temperatur', 'Temp. oben','Temp. mitte', 'Temp. untens']

df = df[df.Zeit.str.contains('Zeit') == False]
df.columns = ['s','segments','mm','kN','%','°C','°C','°C','°C']
df = df[df.s.str.contains('s') == False]
```

Thanks everybody for the help.

I am trying to use pandas to create a new CSV file but the raw.date file has at every x rows 4 rows.

python 2.7

My Code so far:

DATAFILE_INPUT      = 'test.dat'
    DATAFILE_OUTPUT_1   = 'test.out'

```
    in_columns = ['a', 'b', 'c','d']
# read in data (skip some rows / column separator is a tab / no header use our names / decimal separator is a comma)
    df = pd.read_csv(DATAFILE_INPUT, skiprows=1, sep='\t', header=None, names=in_columns, decimal=',')

    out_columns = ['a','b', 'c', 'd']

    df.index += 1

    # save data (filename / print row numbers / tab separator / only print defined columns / decimal separator)
    df.to_csv(path_or_buf=DATAFILE_OUTPUT_1, index=True, sep='\t', columns=out_columns, decimal='.')
```

here a the packages that I use:

```
 import pandas as pd
```

a better example:

```
  In: index a b c d
     0   1,3 1,4  1,32 1,4325 
      1  2,234 2,123 3,123 1,123
     2
    4       name 
    5      guido 
     6     mother 
     7    2,123 2,123123 4,123123 5,123123
     8   1,123123 2,123123 3,123123 4,123123 
     9  1,123123 2,123123 3,123123 4,123123
    10
    11       name 
    12      guido 
     13     mother 
      15    1,2134234 3,34324 3,234234 5,234234
```

and this what I want as output:

```
Out: index a b c d
         0   1.3 1.4  1.32 1.4325 
          1  2.234 2.123 3.123 1.123
         2    2.123 2.123123 4.123123 5.123123
         3   1.123123 2.123123 3.123123 4.123123 
         4  1.123123 2.123123 3.123123 4.123123
          5    1.2134234 3.34324 3.234234 5.234234
```

and so one, what do I have to do the delete, erase, ignore those 4 rows

here is a link to my data sample and to the first result. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/syocsw1l3fyju3q/RF_P92_500_180_023_1.dat?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/syocsw1l3fyju3q/RF_P92_500_180_023_1.dat?dl=0https://www.dropbox.com/s/syocsw1l3fyju3q/RF_P92_500_180_023_1.dat?dl=0)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/or93sk6vxb9z836/test.out?dl=0][2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/or93sk6vxb9z836/test.out?dl=0)

Comment: Why have you copy/pasted code for a question that comments out roughly 50% of the code. It's clearly not relevant, so why include it?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(DATAFILE_INPUT,...` why are you converting this to a `DataFrame`? `pd.read_csv` should be returning a dataframe already.

Comment: Please take a look at how to provide us with [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: @roganjosh I reduced the code already to focus on the issue at large.

Comment: @Dan I ask someone and he told me that a dataframe work much better here. Otherwise if there is any better alternative I am open for that.

Comment: @zipa my sample size is the smallest that I could find.

Comment: @sulphur You don't understand me, I'm saying pd.read_cv(...) will already return a pandas `DataFrame`. You don't need to call `pd.DataFrame` as well

Comment: @Dan sorry you are absolutely right. My question though, what is the difference or why hasn't it produce any Problem, I'm just curious? Thank you every much

Comment: @roganjosh@zipa so I rewrote everything and created a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example so I hope at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `error_bad_lines` to `False` and `warn_bad_lines` to `False` (if you don't, it will print out all bad lines to warn you).

> error_bad_lines : boolean, default True
>
> Lines with too many fields (e.g. a csv line with too many commas) will
>   by default cause an exception to be raised, and no DataFrame will be
>   returned. If False, then these “bad lines” will dropped from the
>   DataFrame that is returned.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./RF_P92_500_180_023_1.dat', sep='\t', skiprows=9,
                 encoding='latin-1', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
```

I ran the above on your provided file but you'll want to take time to verify it has all the lines you want to keep. Shape of resulting dataframe is `(10269,9)`.

---

Alternative, more hands-on approach since this file is in a non-standard format and I have no idea what your expected output looks like (how many columns do you expect?):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# using csv with Pandas

filename = 'RF_P92_500_180_023_1.dat'
header = ['Zeit', 'Zyklus Zähler Zähler', 'Weg',
          'Kraft', 'Dehnung', 'Temperatur', 'Temp. oben',
          'Temp. mitte', 'Temp. untens', 'segments',
          'mm', 'kN', '%', '°C', '°C', '°C', '°C']

data = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 9:
            # flatten a list of lists into single list
            final_row = sum([item.split('\t') for item in row], [])
            data.append(final_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=header)
print(df.shape) # (10046, 17)
```

Comment: @Jared thank you very much, tomorrow I will test it. One question though you mention Shape of resulting dataframe is (10269,9). What does that mean? Sorry if the answer too obvious but I am quite new pandas.Thanks in advance

Comment: It's OK. It means after the dataframe (`df`) is read from the CSV, it has 10,269 rows and 9 columns. You can do `df.shape` to try this.

Comment: so I tried it and I used my original line and modify it yours.  df = pd.read_csv('./RF_P92_500_180_023_1.dat', sep='\t', header=None, names=in_columns, skiprows=10,encoding='latin-1', decimal=',',error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)  but still I get the same error as before. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: seems to be working but their are still 2 NaN rows left as you can see here https://www.dropbox.com/s/or93sk6vxb9z836/test.out?dl=0

Comment: Respectfully, the purpose of my answer was to try and help you along, not do it all for you. For example, there's still rows in that output that are text from the headers. You'll obviously want to drop those rows too. I didn't see the NaN rows you're referring to but there are many ways to inspect rows above and below NaN row and compare to the original file to see what the issue might be. Good luck!

Comment: I am glad you helped me with my question but somehow you are under the impression I am too lazy to find the right solution. That is really odd I spent hours to try to fix the problem may be but from your end, it didn't seem that way. I am fairly new with pandas and I need a solution until 12th of June but that is my problem. Lastly, I hate the saying "good luck" but I don't know why for a non-native speaker it always sounds more like have fun on your own but not really a genuine good luck. Now I will try to remove the multiple headers's popping up in the file.

Comment: How many columns do you expect the output to have? 9 or 17? other? See my modified answer with another approach if working with Pandas becomes too overwhelming given your deadline.

Comment: 9 and those are with their units: time[s],Zyklus[segement],Weg[mm],Force[kN],Strain[%] and then 4 times temperatur[°C]. the 10th must the visible index column if I am not mistaken. I really appreciate the help to give me and I am ego to learn more about Python and Pandas after the I finished the task.

Comment: one more think, this a german system here we use "," instead of ".". But my latter I need "." instead of ",". The Value are sperated but a blank space. That means there really just 9 values + the index. Now I am trying to change your code to that. Agian thank you every much.